# What might cause Oracle to choose parallel execution on one database versus the other for the same objects?

Tags: sql-execution-plan, oracle19c

I have a test and development Oracle 19c database that is running out of temp tablespace on an older pre-existing query. The explain plan shows that, on the database running out of space, the explain plan is using a lot of parallel execution steps (PX SEND BROADCAST, PX RECEIVE, PX BLOCK ITERATOR). The database is also buffering a lot of the scanned data, which I assume is what is causing all the space to get eaten up.

On the dev database, the same query, on the same objects, same indexes, same everything else as far as I have checked, it runs without running out of space. The explain plan uses about half the steps and does not use parallel execution at all.

I am trying to work with one of our DBAs to find what is causing the difference. What are some things I should look at that might explain such a difference in explain plan? I have looked at making sure the indexes are the same, the data size is the same, there have been recent gather stats run, and I have also looked at these settings:

`select PDML_ENABLED, PDML_STATUS, PDDL_STATUS, PQ_STATUS FROM V$session where sid = (select sid from v$mystat where rownum = 1);`

Are there any global or session parameters I might compare between the two databases?

Answer (score 1):

When you say the tables/indexes are the same, make sure to check their "parallel" attribute.
At the system level, check parallel_degree_policy.

Also, an explain plan should tell you why a specific degree or parallelism was chosen; that might provide a clue.